# Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.tomcat v8.5.03

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

So i followed this tutorial by digital ocean on [how to install tomcat on ubuntu](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)
the instructions were okay and i managed to get it up and running.
Next i now wanted to add/install it to my eclipse EE.
when i specify path to find tomcat installation /opt/tomcat i get.

> Unknown version of Tomcat was specified.

ive searched and looked through similar posts on the forum and most of them suggest i find the usr/share/tomcat but when i look through my directories there is no such directory. some suggest i find the var/lib/../tomcat something like that but ive also not gotten any such directory.
most post suggest i find the directory that has the following files.

```
conf/catalina.policy
conf/server.xml
conf/web.xml
conf/context.xml
conf/tomcat-users.xml
 conf/catalina.policy
conf/catalina.properties
lib/catalina.jar
```

in which case mine would be the opt/tomcat and yet i get the error still.
in browser i can acess tomcat using localhost:8080
output of  `sudo systemctl status tomcat`

```
● tomcat.service - Apache Tomcat Web Application Container
 Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/tomcat.service; enabled; vendor preset: e
 Active: active (running) since Lw2 2018-04-17 15:50:22 EAT; 1h 3min ago
 Process: 1022 ExecStart=/opt/tomcat/bin/startup.sh (code=exited, status=0/SUCC
Main PID: 1070 (java)
 CGroup: /system.slice/tomcat.service
       └─1070 /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/java -Djava.util

 Apu 17 15:50:20 alvin-HP-Compaq-6730s systemd[1]: Starting Apache Tomcat Web App
 Apu 17 15:50:21 alvin-HP-Compaq-6730s startup.sh[1022]: Existing PID file found 
 Apu 17 15:50:22 alvin-HP-Compaq-6730s startup.sh[1022]: Removing/clearing stale 
Apu 17 15:50:22 alvin-HP-Compaq-6730s systemd[1]: Started Apache Tomcat Web Appl
```

Comment: Use `which tomcat` to find out where tomcat is installed

Comment: @RonNabuurs where do i use that? it doesnt seem to do anything when i type it in terminal.also i think tomcat is installed in /opt/tomcat though am not sure why eclipse doesnot read it

Comment: If you execute `which tomcat` it should show you the install location where tomcat is installed. What's the output of that command? Also what's the output of `sudo systemctl status tomcat` and are you able to access tomcat through a browser at `localhost:8080` ?

Comment: @RonNabuurs  [which tomcat] outputs nothing .i have edited the question to include output of [sudo systemctl status tomcat]

Comment: Which version of *Eclipse* is this, and does it predate this release of Tomcat?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I encounter the same problem after installing tomcat 8.5 from digital ocean and trying to use it with Eclipse. AlvinMemphis put me on the right path but I couldn't use the full solution. 
However, it showed me the tomcat file was definitely root owned.

To be sure it's the same for you, you can type

`cd /opt/tomcat`

`ll` or `l -l`

To be sure you are changing the ownership of all folders, go back to `/opt`.
You can then type

`sudo chown -R username:group directory`

> /!\ do not forget the -R which will change the ownership of everything in your directory.

In my case I put twice my username, for username and group, and `/tomcat` for the directory.

Once I reloaded the `/opt/tomcat` directory in eclipse, I had no issue anymore.

Be sure to stop tomcat from the command line before using it in eclipse, otherwise you will have an error saying your server is in use.

(`sudo systemctl stop tomcat`)

Answer (score 1):

Don't develop using your production installation. The layout of a packaged Tomcat is decided by whomever packaged it, meaning JARs and configuration files aren't in predictable locations. Grab the tarball directly from Apache and unpack it somewhere else for use during development.

https://wiki.eclipse.org/WTP_Tomcat_FAQ

Answer (score 1):

found a simple fix for the problem.
as it turns out in the tutorial by [digital ocean](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-apache-tomcat-8-on-ubuntu-16-04) and gave them rights to the `opt/tmocat` folder.
so when eclipse tries to load the folder it does so as root and as it turns out root does not have access to this particular folder so in turn eclipse doesnt get to view the files

> `conf/catalina.policy conf/server.xmlconf/web.xml conf/context.xml
>   conf/tomcat-users.xml conf/catalina.policy conf/catalina.properties
>   lib/catalina.jar`

that are required to determine the tomcat version and therefore returns the `cannot determine tomcat version error`
A simple fix is to change the folder rights to root or user and give read and write access.
this can be done using the graphical editor by typing

```
gksu nautilus
```

make sure that gksu is installed if not

```
sudo apt-get install gksu
```

when the home folder opens you are in the mode to change access rights graphically.
navigate to the `/opt/tomcat` and right click to view properties.
here in permisions it shows that the folder is owned by tomcat.
change that to your user name or root and give read and write access.
when that is done. go back to eclipse and everything should install right.
foward thought you may also want to get eclipse to take over system tomcat instead of using its own inbuilt as its possible your work folders are different from the official work folders that eclipse expects i.e there is no  `$Catalina/Home` if you followed digitalOcean tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu, the application doesn't have default permission to read/edit all the folders.

Change the permission for tomcat to 755 and it will work.

```
sudo chmod -R 755 /opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.24/
```